# subtraction Minutes and Seconds from Data in PL\SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table contains information about calls, each call has `start date`, and `end date` with the following format :

**YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS**

how to take the difference between ***start date*** and ***end date*** in minutes or seconds ?

and how to delete seconds or minutes from Date ?, for example (2015-12-23 20:20:50) - 10 seconds = 2015-12-23 20:20:40

Comment: is the data stored in a DATE column ? If so, format is irrelevant. If it's in a string, highly recommend you store it in a DATE and avoid all the drama.

Comment: @Ditto yup the value is stored in column with Date type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're after??

```
  drop table junk;

  create table junk (
     id          number,
     start_date  date,
     end_date    date
     )
  /

  insert into junk values ( 1, to_date('23-dec-2015 20:20:40', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('23-dec-2015 20:20:50', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') );
  insert into junk values ( 1, to_date('23-dec-2015 20:20:40', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('23-dec-2015 20:21:50', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') );
  insert into junk values ( 1, to_date('23-dec-2015 20:20:40', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('23-dec-2015 22:21:50', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') );

  commit;

  select id, start_date, end_date,
         end_date - start_date   diff_days,
         (end_date - start_date)*24   diff_hrs,
         (end_date - start_date)*24*60   diff_min,
         (end_date - start_date)*24*60*60   diff_sec,
         trunc(end_date,'MI')   no_seconds
    from junk
  /

          ID START_DATE           END_DATE              DIFF_DAYS   DIFF_HRS   DIFF_MIN   DIFF_SEC NO_SECONDS
  ---------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
           1 23-dec-2015 20:20:40 23-dec-2015 20:20:50 .000115741 .002777778 .166666667         10 23-dec-2015 20:20:00
           1 23-dec-2015 20:20:40 23-dec-2015 20:21:50 .000810185 .019444444 1.16666667         70 23-dec-2015 20:21:00
           1 23-dec-2015 20:20:40 23-dec-2015 22:21:50 .084143519 2.01944444 121.166667       7270 23-dec-2015 22:21:00

  SQL>
```

[edit]
just noticed I think you might have also been asking to delete a set # of seconds from a date value.

So if we want to delete 15 days, we could:

`end_date - 15`

to delete 15 hours:

`end_date - (15/24)`

... etc, until 15 seconds:

`end_date - (15/24/60/60)`

;)